# ALLOYUI Datepicker setter and getter method

Tags: datepicker, liferay, yui, liferay-aui, alloy-ui

I have two input text box startdate and enddate

```
<input type="text" id="startdate"/>
<input type="text" id="enddate"/>
```

I need two simple things

1. On click of startdate and selection of start date, need to update
   end date with +7 days.

Format needed is mm/dd/yyyy

So if any one click startdate with 01/01/2015 i.e 1st January 2015 , than end date should automatically set with 01/08/2015

2. On selection of startdate, I need to get enddate open automatically.

The datepicker Library I had used is ALLOYUI datepicker version 3.0 
http://alloyui.com/examples/datepicker/

Can anyone please write down code please.

Guys

```
<script>
            var datefrom;
        YUI().use(
  'aui-datepicker',
  function(Y) {
    datefrom = new Y.DatePicker(
      {
        trigger: '#dpfrom',
        popover: {
          zIndex: 1
        },
        calendar: {
                //maximumDate : new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth()+1,today.getDate()),
                minimumDate : new Date(),
                },

        on: {
            selectionChange: function(event) {

          }
        }
      }
    );
  }
);


    //console.log(james);

    </script>
```

I found the may to set  minimum and maximum date but still i donot have the way to set end date +7 days to current date.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show what you have tried so far. This site is meant for questions and answers, rather than requests for others to do your work for you :)

Comment: Hello Russel, 
<script>
 
  YUI().use(
  'aui-datepicker',
  function(Y) {
    new Y.DatePicker(
      {
        trigger: '#startdate',
        popover: {
          zIndex: 1
        },
  Calendar : {
   maximumDate : '01/01/2016'
  },
        on: {
          selectionChange: function(event) {
            console.log(event.newSelection)
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }
);
 
 
 
 
 </script>
 
This is the script, I need to have minimum date as current date using alloyyui. 

#2 On click on startdate , I want the enddate with 7days from today

Comment: YUI().use(
  'aui-datepicker',
  function(Y) {
    new Y.DatePicker(
      {
        trigger: '#frmdate',
        popover: {
          zIndex: 1
        },
  Calendar : {
   maximumDate : '01/01/2016'
  },
        on: {
          selectionChange: function(event) {
            console.log(event.newSelection)
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }
);

Comment: Edit your original question and format the code so it is easily readable for others. Keep it mind that you want to ***help others help you***. Take the time to write and structure your question as clearly as possible

Comment: @Russell thank you for help. I had added code.

Comment: Due to [AUI-1851](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/AUI-1851), I'm not sure your first request will work. However, I will try to find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Please find similar and working one for me. Please customize it if you need anything.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="selecteddate" placeholder="Day, Mon dd, yyyy"></input>

YUI().use(
              'aui-datepicker',
              function(Y) {
                  var datepicker = new Y.DatePicker(
                  {
                    trigger: 'input',
                    popover: {
                      zIndex: 1
                    },
                    after: {
                      selectionChange: function(event) {                      
                            event.preventDefault();     
                            Y.log(datepicker.getSelectedDates());
                            var myDate=Y.DataType.Date.addDays(new Date(datepicker.getSelectedDates()),+6);                       
                            if (myDate.isValid()) {                         
                                $("#selecteddate").val(myDate);
                            }                           
                      }
                    }
                  }
                );
              }
            );


    Date.prototype.isValid = function () {
        // An invalid date object returns NaN for getTime() and NaN is the only
        // object not strictly equal to itself.
        return this.getTime() === this.getTime();
    };
```